# If A is a matrix with the proterty that A=its inverse then show that the determinant of A if 1 or -1

Tags: linear-algebra

Im terrible at proofs and i'm not sure how to approach this
If A is a matrix with the property that A=its inverse then show that the determinant of A if 1 or -1

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** remember that for matrices $A$ and $B$, $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$.  In this case, $A^2 = I$.

Comment: so could i say. If A=A-1 then A^2=I, AA=I, det(A)det(A)=det(I), det(A)det(A)=1?

Comment: Yes, you could absolutely say that.  Can you see how that answers the question?

Comment: That makes sense to me but i am still a little torn by when it says -1 as well or does the (or) in the question literally mean i only have to find one of the solutions?

Comment: What we need to show is that if $A = A^{-1}$, then either $\det(A) = 1$ or $\det(A) = -1$.  What we've shown so far is if $A = A^{-1}$, then $[\det(A)]^2 = 1$.  If $[\det(A)]^2 = 1$, then what are the values that $\det(A)$ can be equal to?

Comment: ohhhhh cause it makes an absolute value which would mean its 1 or -1